# nativescript - Verification failed while extracting tns-android

Tags: android, npm, nativescript

This is the error I get! I have no idea what to do next!

```
$ tns platform add android
Copying template files...
Verification failed while extracting tns-android@6.4.1:
sha512-gPHZi4EA+f39jvJRt5DTSA19Yk0jPAeWWxABd26GUbEU43i1ISnIg0/en42MeWaUjHDXk1Fc1hPXWbIcoEjKiQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-gPHZi4EA+f39jvJRt5DTSA19Yk0jPAeWWxABd26GUbEU43i1ISnIg0/en42MeWaUjHDXk1Fc1hPXWbIcoEjKiQ== but got sha512-AfBUS4i8o0XL1i9MWw0eYhjeM1UW8KOXUbyGInhdPmpytri11XZsPBPE2ToNavy1ljo/rTw3/NBzpD5UP09Llg==. (7416194 bytes)
```

I also manually changed the version in my package.json and this happened:

```
Verification failed while extracting tns-android@6.5.0:
sha512-L7vxid4dSGD6CRS9I2HXCeovuSnChCPNmgmScv5K2qIAOLwcPHcQ77oI3gqEWzMIcNDYjmVFGDR0qjzaKxmydw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-L7vxid4dSGD6CRS9I2HXCeovuSnChCPNmgmScv5K2qIAOLwcPHcQ77oI3gqEWzMIcNDYjmVFGDR0qjzaKxmydw== but got sha512-pleOzs6WMvCDiueDSYDy4NQ1e2eTJmSUEAZqAnIjdW/Fp5qpBf/WRAwOPrg7aMl9Zgi4Eyb+CkSpVFN+cJ/kfg==. (9054579 bytes)
```

clearing cache and deleting the `platforms` and `node_modules` directories works, but I get this when I try to clear `npm cache` without `--force` why?

```
$ npm cache clean        
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
```

Comment: Did you try clearing NPM cache? Also delete your node modules & package lock in project root?

Comment: when I try to delete npm cache it says there is no need. then I forced and deleted node_modules and platforms but it didn't help.

Comment: I did one more time and this time it worked... can you explain to me what was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your project with nativescript 6.5.0.

1.Update nativescript using this command:-

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

2.If your code is not migrate with nativescript 6 then use this command:-

```
tns migrate
```

3.After update your project node_modules and tns_core_modules:-

```
tns update
```

4.Add platform

```
tns platform add android
```